# Кодировка url с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Помогите с файлом *.htaccess*

Помощь в чем? Увидел на сайте [computerlessons.ru](http://computerlessons.ru/lessons/php/1.html) статью, у меня не работает :(

*Что я хочу*.

Есть url - *http://site.com/index.php*

А хотелось, что бы показывало в обозревателе *http://site.com/index.html* и другие php файлы отображались также.

Скажите, что писать в файле `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну или чтоб не заморачиваться в будущем, можно сделать для всех файлов сразу:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

или если хотите чтобы запросы с .html всегда на .php перенаправлялись, то можно обойтись и без проверки на существование файла (флаг -f):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Тоже не фурычит на Денвере, может на платном хостинге заработает.

  Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

Вот что выдало

Comment: Модуль mod_rewrite на сервере установлен?

проверь, выполнив функцию phpinfo();

Comment: Работает вроде. прописан

Comment: а вообще .htaccess на сервере разрешен?

Comment: Да, хотя это и Денвер. V-5.3.2ru

Comment: У Вас Apache файл найти не может index.html. Поменяйте местами index.html и index.php и все заработает...

Comment: @Dobby007, точно же, тупонул я, сорри

Comment: не фурычит:(

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть хорошее описание по кодировке http://help-host.ru/site/htaccess/16-russkaya-kodirovka-cherez-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

**Забирай**:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```